# ObjectiveC UISwitch set default to OFF

Tags: objective-c, uiswitch

How can I set the default value of my UISwitch object to Off? I am probably missing something obvious?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As mmccomb and Bruno Koga mentioned, this can be done programmatically.  In this case, though--assuming that your UISwitch is getting unpacked from a nib--it may be more convenient to simply configure your UISwitch in Interface Builder.

To do this, open the xib that your switch is in, select your switch and open the Attributes Inspector (†) and within the "Switch" section, change the value of "State" from "On" to "Off":

[image: Change the UISwitch's state from On to Off.]

---

† To open the Attributes inspector, first depress the right-end item ("Utilities") in the "View" segmented control at the far right of Xcode's toolbar

[image: Depress the Utilites item in the View segmented control.]

Once the Utilities Area appears with the Inspector Pane above the Library Pane, and select the Attributes Inspector item from the Inspector selector bar

[image: Select the Attributes Inspector item from the Inspector selector bar.]

All of this terminology comes from this image from [Apple's Xcode documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/000-About_Xcode/about.html).

[image: Xcode 4 workspace.]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming tha you have a reference for your `UISwitch`, you could simply override the `-viewDidLoad` method on your controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [yourSwitch setOn:NO animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the setOn:animated: method...

```
- (void)setOn:(BOOL)on animated:(BOOL)animated
```

e.g.

```
[someSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
```

[UISwitch Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: First of all thanks. I read that page but what I think I need (and missing) is a way to set the UISwitch to Off when my screen loaded for the first time.

Comment: Try adding the call to setOn:animated in your view controller's viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Thank you both. Sorry for the delay in coming back to you guys.